# HTML5 video as background

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to use an html5 video as a background for a single full page site however in chrome the video initially loads on top of all of the content until the user attempts to scroll.

The styles for the CSS are below

```
video#bgvid { 
position: fixed; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
width: auto; 
height: auto; 
z-index: -1000;
background: url(../images/video-fallback.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover; 
}
```

Sample on how content is laid out on the site (the bg is set with a transparent color so the interior content is placed outside of it)

```
.header-bg {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
background-color: #000;
z-index: 5;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: .7;
    -webkit-opacity: .7;
        -moz-opacity: .7;
}

header {
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<video autoplay loop poster="images/video-fallback.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="teaser.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="teaser.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>


<div class="header-bg"></div>

<header>
    <img src="images/logo.png">
</header>
```

Any idea on why the video is loading on top of the content in chrome?

Comment: Can we see it live somewhere? Maybe you should try the absolute position.

Comment: Can you not just index it behind everything?  I've never done anything like that before, just spitballing really!

Comment: Add `position:relative` to the div containing `video` and `header`.